# Does WebAuthn support finding out where passkeys are stored?

Tags: authentication, web, webauthn, passkey

When I was trying out creating passkeys for my Google account, I was surprised to see that it knew where my passkey was stored (1Password, iCloud Keychain, security key etc).

Now, I have been studying the WebAuthn protocol for some time now, and have even looked at the protocol extensions, but I couldn't find anywhere a way to obtain information on what kind of a passkey the user is registering.

Is this supported by WebAuthn? I think it would be a nice alternative to requiring the user to provide a nickname for their passkeys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [attested credential data](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#attested-credential-data) that is returned when creating a WebAuthn credential contains an AAGUID, which is an opaque 16-byte value. It is often all zeros but, if not, it identifies the make & model of a security key, or else a passkey provider.

Some values for passkey providers are listed at https://github.com/passkeydeveloper/passkey-authenticator-aaguids/blob/main/aaguid.json

Answer (score 0):

As said @agl, during registration, the result **may** contain an "AAGUID", which is basically the authenticator ID.

Interestingly, the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-3/) mentions multiple times:

> For example, the FIDO Metadata Service [FIDOMetadataService] provides one way to access such information.

If you dig enough in the spec and google searches, you'll end up with the giant JWT located here: https://mds.fidoalliance.org ...And, after parsing, you will end up with something like this: https://github.com/passwordless-id/webauthn/blob/main/src/authenticatorMetadata.ts ...it would be time for me to update that list.

Using that library, you can also directly extract the name of the authenticator. When playing around the [playground](https://webauthn.passwordless.id/demos/playground.html) you can see the parsed payload which may then look as follows.

```json
{
  "username": "Arnaud",
  "credential": {
    "id": "3924Hh...",
    "publicKey": "MFkwEwY...",
    "algorithm": "ES256"
  },
  "authenticator": {
    ...
    "name": "Windows Hello Hardware Authenticator"
  },
  ...
}
```

Please note that mapping the AAGUID to the name is a convenience function of the library, it's not in the raw data. Also, once again theory and reality clash. The latter "metadata services" contains lots of *hardware* authenticators mostly, while the community-driven [project](https://github.com/passkeydeveloper/passkey-authenticator-aaguids) appears to be *software* authenticators mostly (a.k.a. password managers). In the end, both are lacking and you'll need a combination of both for the sake of completeness.

Last but not least, it's insufficient anyway. If you have three windows devices, it's useless to have three times "Windows Hello" as authenticator name. You still don't know which device it is. Although, for passkeys synced by password managers, that is enough since it's in the cloud anyway.